# How to remove vertical space between figure's caption and text

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

My code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\floatplacement{table}{H}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\RequirePackage
[
    skip=0pt,
    format=plain,
    labelsep=endash,
    singlelinecheck=false,
]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=true}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \setlength\floatsep{0pt}
    \setlength\textfloatsep{0pt}
    \setlength\intextsep{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
Text text Text text Text text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text text
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
    \caption{figure}
\end{figure}
Text text Text text Text text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text text
\begin{table}
    \caption{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
        \hline
        Text & Text \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I get vertical space below figure's caption. I would like to remove it. How to achieve this? Also, it's secondary, but I would like to know how to remove spacing between table and it's caption.

Please, don't pay attention that table's caption bumps into text, this code only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: It would be nice if you tell how to configure spacing before table's caption globally.

Comment: well as a first step you shouldn't set all float spaces to 0pt.

Comment: My current task was to understand how to remove this skip.

Comment: I cannot see any difference (aside the other page format and not available font size) using `report` instead of `scrreprt`. So your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @cabohah I tried it now, and you are right. I checked it yesterday and concluded that the problem is with `KOMA-Script`. Probably, I'm wrong. Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Intolighter I've completely changed your question to show the real problem, that is independent from KOMA-Script. If this is not what you want, you can revert it.